# Какая рекуррентная формула?

Tags: c++, математика, рекурсия, формулы

Помогите решить задачу не пойму какая тут формула
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подсказка: очередное число рассчитывается на основе двух предыдущих.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он вобще не про ИТ

Comment: @extrn, если выкинуть число 1, то рассчитывается на основе предыдущего

Comment: @Xander, но тег "математика" же есть

Comment: @Zhihar ну не зная следующих элементов последовательности можно много чего предположить, но насколько я понимаю, дальше будет 27/16 и 53/32

Comment: [www.wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2C+2%2C+3%2F2%2C+7%2F4%2C+13%2F8): `a(n+2) = (a(n) + a(n+1)) / 2`.

Answer (score 3):

```
float a(int n)
{ 
    return (n == 1 || n == 2) ? n : (a(n - 2) + a(n - 1)) / 2; 
}
```